# How shall I generate a pdf file instead of a ps file using enscript?

Tags: pdf, ps, printing, cups, enscript

I was wondering why the following generates a ps file not a pdf file?
How can I make it generate a pdf file? Thanks.

```
$ enscript -B -PPDF code/bloom.c -o bloom.pdf 
[ 2 pages * 1 copy ] left in bloom.pdf
$ file bloom.pdf 
bloom.pdf: PostScript document text conforming DSC level 3.0
```

I have already installed cups-pdf by

```
sudo apt install cups-pdf
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

By default, `enscript` only makes postscipt file (ps).

Your command line is missing two flags: *small* `-p` and *capital* `-P`. The command line must be like this:

```
enscript -B -P <PDF_PRINTER_NAME> code/bloom.c -p myfile.ps
```

According to `enscript` [manpage](https://www.systutorials.com/docs/linux/man/1-enscript/)

```
-P name, --printer=name
Spool the output to the printer name.

-p file, --output=file
Leave the output to file file. If the file is `-', enscript sends the output to the standard output stdout.
```

If a pdf printer in not available in the system, then [ghostscript](https://www.ghostscript.com/) can convert the ps file to pdf file as follows:

```
sudo apt install ghostscript
ps2pdf myfile.ps myfile.pdf
```

or

```
enscript file -o - | ps2pdf - output.pdf
```

When pdf printer is default in the system, then something like this command, will output pdf files instead of the ps files:

```
enscript -2 -r -j --font=Times-Roman11 --word-wrap --mark-wrapped=arrow '%f' && sleep 2 && evince ~/PDF/_stdin_.pdf

- The `%f` designates the filename parameter.    
- The `&& sleep 2 &amp;&amp; evince ~/PDF/_stdin_.pdf` commands will wait two seconds for the print job to finish, then run the Evince PDF viewer to display the file _stdin_.pdf you just generated in the user’s PDF subdirectory.
```

Comment: Thanks. Why does `-PPDF` not make it create pdf file directly? Is it the case on your linux?

Comment: How would you " set your default Printer in the system to the PDF printer"? Does `-PPDF`  already specify the printer to be the PDF printer?

Comment: Is there a reliable command which will work in both cases with or without making the PDF printer default?

Comment: Thanks. Is this your preferred way to convert a text file to a pdf file? What is it if not?

Comment: May I also ask why `enscript -2 -r -j --font=Times-Roman11 --word-wrap --mark-wrapped=arrow code/bloom.c` create a pdf file directly? The options have nothing to do with it. I found that `-o` might be the cause, but don't understand why it is.

Comment: My pdf printer is named `PDF`. `enscript -B --printer=PDF code/bloom.c -p myfile.pdf` and `enscript -B -P PDF code/bloom.c -p myfile.pdf` and `enscript -B -PPDF code/bloom.c -p myfile.pdf` all create ps file not pdf file. Not sure why that is and what you mean.

Comment: How shall I verify the name of the PDF printer? `-PPDF` without `-o` or `-p` creates pdf, so I don't think `-PPDF` is wrong.

Comment: `system default destination: PDF`. `-PPDF` without `-o` or `-p` creates pdf under `~/PDF/`, so I don't think `-PPDF` is wrong. `-o` or `-p` is the cause, but I don't know why.

Comment: `-P PDF` and `-PPDF` work the same in my previous comment.